# Cross-browser version of "all: initial"

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-reset

I am trying to use `all: initial` to isolate the CSS for a special "widget" in the page. The problem is that Safari and IE10 and earlier don't support the [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) property and IE doesn't support the [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) value.

Is there a way to emulate the same behaviour, using either CSS or JavaScript?

For example, I imagine it would be possible to create a CSS class which contains every property defined by the CSS spec and sets them to the initial value specified by the spec. Is there a CSS class out there which already does that?

If I google "CSS reset" I get a bunch of stylesheets intended specifically to normalise the differences between user-agent stylesheets, which is different from `all: initial`.

Answer (score 5):

Even if all browsers will support `all: initial`, it wont be cross-browser.

`all: initial` cant be cross-browser by definition, because:

1. initial values of `font-family` and `quotes` depends on UserAgent
2. initial value of `color` varies from Browser To Browser
3. initial value of [`text-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust) depends on browsers support for Inflation *(though, its experimental)*

**Update (01 march 2017):**:

4. vendors' `appearance` properties: (`-webkit-appearance`, `-moz-appearance`, `-ms-appearance`) are none, but overridden In User-Agent CSS.
5. List of 14 properties depends on `currentcolor`, which is reference to property `color`, which varies from browser to browser (hence 2nd point), and aforementioned list is: `-webkit-border-before-color`, `-webkit-text-fill-color`, `-webkit-text-stroke-color`, `border-block-end-color`, `border-block-start-color`, `border-bottom-color`, `border-inline-end-color`, `border-inline-start-color`, `border-left-color`, `border-right-color`, `border-top-color`, `column-rule-color`, `text-decoration-color`, `text-emphasis-color`.
6. Property: `outline-color` is either `currentColor` or inverted one, depends on the browser

also marked `text-size-adjust` as experimental in initial post

**Update (08 march 2017):**:

7. Property: `text-align` is either `left` or `right` initially, depends on the `direction`, which `all: initial` doesnt override accordingly to specification.

Answer (score 1):

The `initial` keyword value was introduced in 2011 in the [Cascading and Inheritance Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/) -- it's supported in FF 19+, Chrome, Safari, Opera 15+ but is [currently not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#keywords) in any version of IE.

This has no synonym to this purpose. Your only solutions is to trust in normalizers or handmake all your properties and values depending on browser (very hard work)

Answer (score 0):

This PostCSS plugin could help: [postcss-initial](https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-initial).

It could fix browsers inconsistency by setting initial values manually. But it is open question, is it future-proof. But until you use plugin, you will have same result.

Comment: this plugin is nice, but it sets initial values not for all css properties, rather half of them

Comment: Ouh, could you send PR with a fix?

Comment: sure, i will right after i will finish with mine polyfill